# The Mysterious Area

Tags: riddle

I have keys but no locks.

I have a space but no room.

You can enter, but can’t go outside.

**What am I?**

Comment: I'd argue, though, that the answer does, in fact, have locks.

Comment: Once you enter, you can't go out but can you escape?

Comment: I came here expecting an awesome visual puzzle or something along the lines of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18608/37225, and here I am, stuck with this poorly-constructed riddle (see NSBD's comment on answer below).

Comment: In fact, almost exact duplicate! I'll flag it instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are...

> A keyboard

I have keys but no locks.

> Well, it's right there in the name, isn't it?

I have a space but no room.

> What have I hit between words? *Spacebar!*

You can enter, but can’t go outside.

> What have I hit between lines? *Enter!*

Comment: Mine has three locks; caps, scroll and num.