# Room 4 of the Maze

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, password

This is Room 4 of the Maze series. For those wishing to start from the beginning, click [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18567/room-1-of-the-maze)

You wake up in Room 4 after a troubled night of 'sleep'. Your head was clouded all night with thoughts of geography, chemistry, and math. "What's coming next?", you wonder as you head for the note. But instead of a note on the platform, you see that the platform is glowing like a computer screen, showing a page on your favorite site, the Puzzling StackExchange! You realize that the platform is a sort of touch-screen interface so you attempt to navigate to an emergency service site, but all you can see on the interface is a question and the edit, close, and flag buttons. Even the add comment and add answer features are missing. Baffled, you scroll and read the question:

> Welcome to Room 4 of the Maze! You have officially made it farther than any of the other test subjects. You humans have an expression, "Out of the frying pan and into the fire"; if we understand it correctly, your current situation is an apt application of that idiom. From here on, the puzzles get noticeably harder. You're going to have to start thinking outside of the box if you want to live, but we have faith that you're up for the challenge. Good Luck!!
>
> Key 1:COPY
>
> STOP
>
> Key 2:
>   124 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 10 10 124 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 113 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 10 67 53 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 113 32 32 32 113 32 32 32 32 101 10 124 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 101 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 101 32 32 32 101 32 32 101 32 101 10 124 45 124 113 45 45 45 113 45 45 45 124 101 45 101 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 10 35 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 101 10 124 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 124 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 101 32 32 32 101 32 32 101 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 113 10 67 52 10

The keypad on the door has only digits. It holds enough room on the display for 3 digits. You can faintly see fingerprints on some of the keys. "That's odd; I thought no one had ever made it this far...", you think to yourself. Shaking your head to concentrate, you turn back to the bewildering information on the screen and get to work.

Answer from [Previous Room](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18608/room-3-of-the-maze):

> 117

This room has been solved. Normally I would wait until the next morning to post the next room, but figured I'd give the night shift a chance. Are you any closer to escaping the Maze? What's the next subject matter? Will anyone ever get sent to the universe of Bud Light Lime? Find out in the [next installment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/room-5-of-the-maze)!

Comment: I knew when I made that comment about the aliens being geniuses that I would eventually mess something up. That said, *you look back at the screen, thinking you saw a typo and realize that there was a 101 there the whole time. Now the maze has you seeing things.* Good thing the screen doesn't show an edit history ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code to enter is:

> The same as the previous room, 117

Key 1 is morse code with spaces being dots and tabs being dashes.  This yields the text:

> SUMFREQFLOORADD6049ADDAFPRSQRT

Key 2 is, as [f'' figured out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18671/6144) is decimal ascii representation.  Converting this to ascii code yields:

```
|-|--------|--------|--------|--------|

|-|--------|----q---|--------|--------|
C5                   q   q    e
|-|--------|---e----|--------|--------|
                        e   e  e e
|-|q---q---|e-e-----|--------|--------|
#                               e
|-|--------|--------|--------|--------|
      e   e  e                    q
C4
```

Converting all of the notes in the key signature to their [frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies) gives us this:

```
0 x 698.456 |-|--------|--------|--------|--------|
0 x 659.255 
1 x 587.330 |-|--------|----q---|--------|--------|
3 x 523.251 C5                   q   q    e
1 x 493.883 |-|--------|---e----|--------|--------|
4 x 440.000                        e   e  e e
4 x 391.995 |-|q---q---|e-e-----|--------|--------|
1 x 369.994 #                               e
0 x 329.628 |-|--------|--------|--------|--------|
4 x 293.665      e   e  e                    q
0 x 261.626 C4
```

Following the instructions in Key 1:

```
SUMFREQ = sum of the frequencies = 7523.600
FLOOR(SUMFREQ) = 7523
FLOOR(SUMFREQ) + 6049 = 13572
FLOOR(SUMFREQ) + 6049 + AFPR (answer from previous room = 117) = 13689
SQRT(FLOOR(SUMFREQ) + 6049 + AFPR) = 117
```

Comment: Well done Leppy. Enjoy your victory while I triple check Room 5 and continue to wonder if the rng is ever going to send anyone to BudLightLime-iverse

Comment: @NeedAName Here's hoping it's at least Heinekeniverse.

Comment: You can get a link to an answer (or a question, for that matter) using the "share" button beside the "edit" button. For comment, the "timestamp" is a link (and you can copy the address by right clicking).

Answer (score 10):

Converting the numbers in Key 2 into ASCII results in this:

```
|-|--------|--------|--------|--------|

|-|--------|----q---|--------|--------|
C5                   q   q    e
|-|--------|---e----|--------|--------|
                        e   e  e e
|-|q---q---|e-e-----|--------|--------|
#                               e
|-|--------|--------|--------|--------|
      e   e  e                    q
C4
```

This is a picture of a musical score. The piece is "Eine kleine Nachtmusik" by Mozart, which has a catalog number of 525.

The source of the question shows a bunch of spaces, tabs, and newlines in Key 1. Here they are with spaces replaced by S and tabs by T:

```
SSS
SST
TT
SSTS
STS
S
TTST
SSTS
STSS
TTT
TTT
STS
ST
TSS
TSS
TSSSS
TTTTT
SSSST
TTTTS
ST
TSS
TSS
ST
SSTS
STTS
STS
SSS
TTST
STS
T
```

This looks like a Whitespace program, but it seems to be broken.

I can't figure out what to do with the previous part's answer. Without any other information, 525 is the only three-digit number related to anything here.

Comment: It's a shame that "wow." is fewer than the character limit because that's the comment I'd like to leave here.

Comment: I agree with @BaileyM. Though not  yet done of course, you did a number on what I thought was quite the challenge. Keep up the great work and you should have the final answer in no time. And Key 1 is not a whitespace program.

Comment: Do you know something older that ALSO looks like a Whitespace program?  The length of these lines is pretty significant.  (I don't have time to solve this, but I know what you're looking at there)

Comment: @f" Leppy pointed out that the 4th 113 in the original post was changed to 101 (3rd C5 quarter note changed to eighth note). This won't affect the final answer, but is something you may care to correct for accuracy's sake.

Comment: @NeedAName I already fixed it for f''